# Однозначная лемматизация слов русского текста

Tags: python, морфология

Текст состоит из правильных в меру предложений русского языка.
Можно использовать pymorphy2 — будут выданы варианты, как в классическом примере СТАЛИ — Veb, Noun. Как опираясь на информацию соседствующих в предложении слов правильно выбрать единственный правильный вариант. Буду благодарен за идеи, алгоритмы, примеры на python, готовые модули в которых это работает.

Comment: Косой косой косил косой косой, стекло стекло, а покрывало покрывало покрывало.

Comment: @Эникейщик попугай, попугай, попугай :)

Comment: Добавьте пример текста. Если предложения более - менее стандартные (к примеру, повествавательные, порядок слов без вариаций), то можно что-то придумать.

Answer (score 3):

Выбор однозначных гипотез во многих случаях - задача нетривиальная:

> [Он видел их семью своими глазами](https://habr.com/en/post/152799/)
>
> [image: Он видел их семью своими глазами]

(У меня есть такая оранжевая майка с этим симпатичным семиглазиком) ;)

Вы можете использовать размеченные корпусы русского языка, чтобы составить свой алгоритм. В простейшем случае вы можете просто [использовать](http://opencorpora.org/?page=downloads) готовые частотности на опорных текстах и полагаться на то, что и у вас будет примерно такое же совпадение.

Как человек, вручную снявший неоднозначность в сотнях тысяч разнородных примеров для открытого корпуса могу только пожелать удачи в вашей затее.

Answer (score 0):

На python, использую pymorphy2 и машинное обучение:

https://github.com/chomechome/maru

https://github.com/IlyaGusev/rnnmorph

Инструменты для NLP с исходниками на github

http://www.solarix.ru/

Comment: Сообщения содержащие только ссылки на внешние ресурсы, ответом не считаются. Добавте основное из ссылок прямо  в тело сообщения.